# How to play own CSS animation before element is removed?

Tags: svelte

There are already questions on this (non Svelte specific...), and the solution that is often proposed, is to instead of directly removing the element, first set the animation class and an event handler and then remove the element on animationend.

In Svelte the creation and removal of an element is 'automatically' handled by for example an `{#if}` or `{#each}` block.

There are "build in" [`transitions`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-transition-fn) to animate an element on creation/destruction

> A transition is triggered by an element entering or leaving the DOM as a result of a state change.

When examining an element with a transition set, it can be seen that Svelte creates an animation which is played before the element is finally removed.

[image]
[image]

There's the option to write a [custom transition function](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-transition-fn-custom-transition-functions) which then creates an animation

> If the returned object has a css function, Svelte will create a CSS animation that plays on the element.

**The main question is:** What if there's already a more complex CSS animation that should not only play when the element enters the dom, but also before it's destroyed? How can this be achieved?

Here are two Repls related to this [#1](https://svelte.dev/repl/39adf099ec5249009e2a5b78cfdebbb2?version=3.46.6) + [#2](https://svelte.dev/repl/1232789f583742849560057ceb93b994?version=3.46.6)
While the second seems to do what is asked for, it is a workaround and there might be a better way?

**Edit** I assume this question is missing a concrete example which can be solved. If that's so, here it is [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/14839169328c4410b8bfc58df2992be0?version=3.46.6)

```
<script>
    import {imgData} from './svg'
    
    export let visible = false;
</script>

<button on:click={() => visible = !visible}>click</button><br>

<!-- The animation plays on element creation. How to play it reversed before the element is destroyed? -->
{#if visible}
<img src={imgData} alt="" class="fade-and-slide">
{/if}

<style>
    .fade-and-slide {
        animation: fade-and-slide 1500ms linear;
    }
    @keyframes fade-and-slide {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(100px);
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(100px);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }
</style>
```

*Some additional thoughts*
I assume that Svelte uses the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) to handle the animation? Because

> The `transition: directive` indicates a bidirectional transition, which means it can be smoothly reversed while the transition is in progress.

That would otherwise, by adding removing classes, not possible?

I might be on the wrong track, but I wonder: Since the `css: fn` option of the transition seem to create an animation, couldn't it be possible to implement that the desired keyframes can be passed as option instead like

```
keyframes: [
    { opacity: '0', transform: 'translateY(100px)' },
    { opacity: '1', transform: 'translateY(100px)' },
    { opacity: '1', transform: 'translateY(0)' }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

> (paraphrased) Reusing an existing complex CSS animation for the outro?

Nothing built-in as far as i know, but you've already found some workarounds.

> I assume that Svelte uses the Web Animations API to handle the animation?

Svelte doesn't use the Web Animations API, it calls the css function multiple times and generates the entire animation as a keyframe animation.

See create_rule() in [svelte/runtime/internal/style_manager.ts](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/internal/style_manager.ts)

When an animation is canceled and reversed halfway, Svelte generates a custom reverse animation.

Try rapidly clicking in your #1 repl to see this in action.

> That would otherwise, by adding removing classes, not possible?

By adding or removing classes the css animations would play from beginning to end, not start halfway.
(You'd have to do some  negative `animation-delay` hackery)

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks a lot for the link! While with the workaround I found the animation is played when entering and leaving, it can't be reversed like with the Svelte animation. That's why I was assuming the Web Animations API... don't really get how it's done without yet, but will have a look into this... Thanks!